# Create Fit to HLN Model in Origin

Tags: data-analysis, curve-fitting, analysis

I need to fit my data in Origin to a HLN model, which takes a form similar to this:
[image: Y=a{Ψ(1/2+b/X)-ln(b/X)}]

where (alpha, B_psi) are fitting parameters and the function Ψ is the digamma function. I understand to create a new function in Origin I need to go to Analysis » Fitting » Non-linear fit but after that I don't really know what steps to take to define my intended function after that. I tried using the Python function mode but it turned out to be too complex.

Does anyone know what steps I need to take to define this fit? I also would like to impose bounds on the parameters so I don't get insane values, so the alpha parameter, for example, should only vary between  [0,1.5]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the parameters (a,b) in the function.

Comment: I edited the function and then forgot to update the parameters, it's corrected now

Comment: OK. I suppose that y(x)=sigma(H) is the function which a set of points (y=sigma ; x=H) are measured. Can you joint to the question an example of data (numerical not graphical). What about sigma(0)? Known or unknown parameter ?